# How to update themes in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, theme, upgrade

Currently my site is using `porto 3.1.7` theme. I want to upgrade the theme to `3.2.0`. My version is `Magento 2.3.0`. How can I upgrade the theme. Is there something I need to take care of ? Will it affect my custom code ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to checklist the following point in order to update any theme

> I. Proper preparation for update:

Before updating magento 2 theme, we need to have a well preparation including 4 small steps below:

We suggest duplicating your live store on a development store and trying to update Venustheme version on it in advance.
Backup database of your site: Go to `admin > System > Backup > Backup Database`, then input file name and submit it.
 Backup your modified files of the theme and extensions: app/code/Ves/ and app/design/frontend/Venustheme
Disable all cache related section that you have in your magento.

> II. Detailed process for Theme File Updating:

After the preparation stage, now are you willing to update to last version of theme files?

Here is the best part:

In this tutorial, we will use the theme_files.zip to update the new version for the site.

**Step 1:** Download latest theme package on our site or on Themeforest.net. Then decompress the package on your PC.

**Step 2:** Decompress the file “Theme Files/magento 2.1.0/theme_files.zip” – in the file we stored theme files, theme’s extensions files, sample theme media files.

**Step 3:** Upload the files in theme_files.zip which you just decompressed into the webroot folder in your site (it will override the app/ and pub/ folders in your site).

**Step 4:** Open SSH Terminal of your site, then run there commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But there’s a catch:
Sometimes your site is broken, after run this command, it’s because of you ran this command with the incorrect user. If your site was broken, it’s very important to set the file’s permissions and ownership correctly, after run this command line. You can refer this command chown -R : .
Typical examples:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/magento2/venustheme
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/domain/public_html
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Hashan. Thank you. I would like to know my custom changes on theme will be lost? i need to again do it?

Comment: @Nafisa if your changes in theme core files which are the part of theme release it may update or your changes may lost. I didn't experience theme upgradation. The best way is to take backup of your code and do the above steps

Answer (score 2):

If you have made custom changes to the template files or code in your installed parent Porto 3.1.7 theme these will be lost if you install the 3.2.0 theme update.

The best way to work with a custom theme is to create your own child theme with the custom theme as the parent. In this case you would create a new child theme with Porto 3.1.7 as the parent. If you know which Porto template, code or layout files you have customised you can copy these to your child theme to preserve your changes.

With your child theme working you can then upgrade the parent theme to 3.2.0 without losing your customisations. You can then compare any files you have changed with the update to check for any updates / fixes in the theme you might need to implement yourself.

Before making any changes always backup your Magento source files and database. Make the changes on a test/development server first and test thoroughly before applying to your production server.

The Magento documentation will help you to create a new child theme if you have not done that before.

Comment: Good answer :) +1 for that